# How to change again once you clicked once with onclick in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change back to model 8 after I click to change to model 11 but i can't figure out how?

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/model08.css" id = "style" media="screen" />

<ul>                                        
                    <li class="droite"><span id="clickme">Click me !</span></li>
 </ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
        var element = document.getElementById('clickme');
        var feuilleStyle = document.getElementById('style');
        if(feuilleStyle.href = "styles/model08.css"){
        element.onclick = function()
              {
               document.getElementById('feuille').href = "styles/model11.css";
               return false;
              };      
        }else if(feuilleStyle.href = "styles/modele11.css"){
            ????
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to accompish? Looks like you want to replace the css files when the link is clicked, is this the case?

Comment: Yes, and then when I click again it goes back to the original css. Sorry I just started with JavaScript.

Comment: Why sorry? Everyone has to start somehow! Do you really need to change the files or you just want to update the style of your page?

Comment: Thank you :) I am trying to update the style rather than change the file. I am able to update it once to model 11 (originally model 8) but I'm stuck on how to switch it back to model 8.

Comment: I updated my answer to include an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments on the question, there is no need to create 2 different `CSS` files.

You can add all your `CSS` in the same file, and then with your `JavaScript` just toggle a class on the `html` element.

Something like this:

`CSS` File:

```
#clickme.eight {
    background: red;
}

#clickme.eleven {
    background: blue;
}
```

`HTML` File:

```
<ul>                                        
    <li class="droite">
        <span id="clickme" class="eight" onClick="changeClass">Click me !</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`JavaScript` File:

```
document.getElementById("clickme").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.target.classList.toggle('eight');
    event.target.classList.toggle('eleven');
});
```

I created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anpel13/jo793cvp/) so you can check it in action.

Let me know if this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the click handler inside your if/else. Try creating the if/else inside of the handler like this:

```js
element.onclick = function() {
  if(feuilleStyle.href = "styles/model08.css"){
      document.getElementById('feuille').href = "styles/model11.css";
  } else if(feuilleStyle.href = "styles/modele11.css"){
      document.getElementById('feuille').href = "styles/model08.css";
  }
}
```

Also, I don't see an element with an id of 'feuille' in your html code. So you might want to change `document.getElementById('feuille')` to `feuilleStyle`.

Comment: Right, I changed some element names but I forgot to change them here as well, sorry about that. Also I tried it but it doesn't seem to work. Thank you